# Wicket 7.x handle external resource directory/file requests

Tags: wicket, mount

I wanna handle requests to image resources like this:
    `<img src="images?file=sub/path/to/myImage.jpg" />`

The key "images" is an alias for a mounted resource somewhere on my local hard drive:
    `/base/path/to/all/images`
that contains the subdirectory
    `sub/path/to`
where the requested image
    `myImage.jpg`
is located.
So the full image path is:
    `/base/path/to/all/images/sub/path/to/myImage.jpg`

I've tried to mount a request mapper using:
    `public void WebApplication#mount(final IRequestMapper mapper) {...}`

but I really don't understand what to do.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please check http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/ and the demo application linked at the bottom. It does almost the same.

Comment: As a general rule, answers with just a link are frowned upon. Better to include the salient code fragments in the answer.

Comment: Well possibly, but if the link becomes dead, then future readers of this have nothing. I've posted answers with just links in the past, and people have pointed out that I should include the main points in the answer, not just rely on the link. I'm sure the guidelines of StackOverflow also recommend not posting link-only answers, if I could be bothered to search for it.